# If $x = 5- \sqrt{21}$, find the value of $\dfrac {\sqrt x}{\sqrt{32-2x} - \sqrt{21}}$.

Tags: radicals

**PROBLEM**: If $x = 5- \sqrt{21}$, find the value of $\dfrac {\sqrt x}{\sqrt{32-2x} - \sqrt{21}}$.

**Solution:**

$$x = 5- \sqrt{21}$$

$$\sqrt x = \sqrt {5- \sqrt{21}}$$

I am unable to continue from here.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Irritating - I have finally grasped that the denominator is 1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to notice that
$$\sqrt{22+2\sqrt{21}}=\sqrt{21}+1;$$
$$\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{21}}=\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{3}.$$

In general, if $a\geqslant b\geqslant0$, 
$$\sqrt{a}\pm\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a+b\pm2\sqrt{ab}}.$$
So, when you need to compute $\sqrt{x\pm\sqrt{y}}$, you could have a look if there is any simple solution for $x=a+b$, $y=4ab$.